# Accessing ASP.NET Controls Properties within Parallel.Invoke

Tags: c#, asp.net, task-parallel-library

**Is it safe to access UI control properties as in code below when using Parallel.Invoke method in an ASP.Net page?**

So far I haven't come across any issues but not sure if I am missing something. I am accessing the Text property of 2 textboxes - txtAge and txtName in code below.

```
  protected void Page_Load( object sender, EventArgs e)
  {  
    Parallel.Invoke(() =>
    {
        try
        {
            SetEmployeeName(txtName.Text);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
        }
        catch (Exception e1)
        {
        }
    }, // close first Action

        () =>
        {
            try
            {
                SetEmployeeAge(int.Parse(txtAge.Text), txtName.Text);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
            }
            catch (Exception e2)
            {
            }
        } // close second Action
   );
 }
```

**EDIT 1:**

It seems that the above code may not be thread-safe because Text property of Textbox control is not guaranteed to be thread-safe according to MSDN doumentation.

Answer (score 1):

why don't you store the strings in local variables and then use them in the lambdas, that should be thread safe because you are not modifying them.